# iOS - touchesmoved only once per view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa, ipad

I have a bunch of `UIView` on my main view. I have added the touchesBegan, touchesMoved and touchesEnded functionality to the app.

When moved, the view at the point is being shown multiple times, unless the touch is out of the view's `CGRect`. I would like to refer to each view only once when move over the view and not be considered unless moved out of the CGRect and then back in. Here's my code:

```
-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{

    UITouch *myTouch = [touches anyObject];

    CGPoint point = [myTouch locationInView:self.view];

    UIView *movedView = [self viewAtPoint:point];

    if(movedView != nil)
    {
    NSLog(@"Touches Moved - %@",movedView.name);
    }
}


-(UIView *) viewAtPoint:(CGPoint) point
{   
CGRect touchRect = CGRectMake(point.x, point.y, 1.0, 1.0);

    for( UIView *c in viewArray.views ){
        if( CGRectIntersectsRect(c.frame, touchRect) ){
            return c; 
        }       
    }
    return nil;
}
```

So the `NSLog` dumps the same view multiple times. I want to limit it to only once when moved over the view until moved out of the view again.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep track of the last view that the touch moved into, and then you can optimize your function to check if the touch is still in that view first, before checking against others

Comment: Sometimes it can be the same view twice in a row, but the move has to go outside the view and then back to count it as twice. So if I keep track of the last view I can't get the same view twice in a row.

Comment: Yes you can, you just check if it is still in that view when you move, if it is not, then you reset currentView to nil, then when it moves back into the original view again, it registers as a new hit